# How to make dynamic routes PHP MVC

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

### How do I make a route for /blog/* where * is a slug for a blog post?

I am making a PHP MVC Framework from scratch and I'm making trouble with the showing data in view and how to make so people can click on blog posts to view it!

Please see the github: https://github.com/fillemon10/cinemania-mvc to understand and help me.
I dont know how do deal with retrieving data from database to blog.

index.php:

```
<?php

use app\controllers\AuthController;
use app\controllers\BlogController;
use app\controllers\SiteController;
use app\core\Application;
use app\models\Blog;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();

$config = [
    'userClass' => \app\models\User::class,
    'db' => [
        'dsn' => $_ENV['DB_DSN'],
        'user' => $_ENV['DB_USER'],
        'password' => $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD']
    ]
];

$app = new Application(dirname(__DIR__), $config);
$app->on(Application::EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST, function () {
});

$app->router->get('/', [SiteController::class, 'home']);

$app->router->get('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contact']);
$app->router->post('/contact', [SiteController::class, 'contact']);

$app->router->get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
$app->router->post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
$app->router->get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
$app->router->post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
$app->router->get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
$app->router->get('/myaccount', [AuthController::class, 'myaccount']);

$app->router->get('/blog', [BlogController::class, 'blog']);

$app->run();
```

router.php:

```
<?php

namespace app\core;

use app\core\exception\NotFoundException;

class Router
{
    public Request $request;
    public Response $response;
    protected array $routes = [];

    public function __construct(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->response = $response;
    }

    public function get($url, $callback, $params ="")
    {
        $this->routes['get'][$url] = $callback;
    }

    public function post($url, $callback)
    {
        $this->routes['post'][$url] = $callback;
    }

    public function resolve()
    {
        $url = $this->request->getUrl();
        $method = $this->request->method();
        $callback = $this->routes[$method][$url] ?? false;
        if ($callback === false) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
        if (is_string($callback)) {
            return Application::$app->view->renderView($callback);
        }
        if (is_array($callback)) {
            /** @var \app\core\Controller $controller */
            $controller = new $callback[0]();
            Application::$app->controller = $controller;
            $controller->action = $callback[1];
            $callback[0] = $controller;
            foreach ($controller->getMiddlewares() as $middleware) {
                $middleware->execute();
            }
        }
        return call_user_func($callback, $this->request, $this->response);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have authored the Model.php and UserModel file, you should have a grasp on database interactions.  Perhaps start with a BlogModel?

Comment: This isn't a bug fix question, and I fear it's too broad.  Expect negativity.  Can you refine your question?  Perhaps into 'here is my attempt, it's not working as I expect, why?' format?

Comment: A router should/does NOT dispatch the request. It should just return the names of the searched resources (controller, action, params) - be they encapsulated in a returned object or plain array, if you wish. These names will be later used by a dispatcher, in order to access the resources that they reference.